# How to link Javascript files to HTML recursively

Tags: javascript, php, html, recursion

I'm trying to recursively link some Javascript files in a directory into a HTML page:

```
<?php
    $dir = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project/js';
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

    foreach ( $iterator as $path ) {
        if ($path->isDir()) {
            print('dir >>> ' . $path->__toString() . PHP_EOL . '\n');

        } else {
            print($path->__toString() . PHP_EOL . '\n\n\n');
            echo("<script src='$path->__toString() . PHP_EOL>\</script>");
        }
    }

?>
```

This, however, doesn't seem to work. How can I go about adding all the files in the directory and sub-directories recursively? Any working recursive approach will do. It doesn't have to be the way I'm trying it above.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `however, doesn't seem to work` - okay, _what_ is the issue? Have you simply tried to `echo $path` and see what happens when you run it?

Comment: Please state clearly the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your foreach block to below code and see if that helps?

```
foreach ( $iterator as $path ) {
    if ($path->isDir()) {
        print('dir >>> ' . $path . PHP_EOL);

    } else {
        print($path . PHP_EOL);
        echo("<script src='$path'></script>".PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

The issue was with the syntax of `"<script src='$path->__toString() . PHP_EOL>\</script>"` changing this line to `"<script src='$path'></script>"` will help.